# How to replace multiple String characters?

Tags: java

I have an array of 6 different strings. Right now I'm focused on replacing all letters in the first sentence of the array with different characters. For example all 'r' in the sentence would become 'i' and all 't' would become 'u'. The code I tried below only replaces the characters of the code I've written on the last line. (It replaces all 'p' with 'u' but ignores all of the code above)

How do I replace every character in the sentence?

```
public static void replaceString(String[] arr) {
    
    String s1 = arr[0];
    for (String i: arr) {
        String sentence1 = s1.toLowerCase().replace("a", "t");
        sentence1 = s1.toLowerCase().replace("r", "m");
        sentence1 = s1.toLowerCase().replace("e", "i");
        sentence1 = s1.toLowerCase().replace("s", "n");
        sentence1 = s1.toLowerCase().replace("p", "u");
        System.out.println(sentence1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reuse the same `String` you've assigned on the first line.. I'm sure you'll find which one :)

Comment: why the loop? ... You iterate through all strings, but never use them? `i` is ignored at so many levels..and sentence printed so many times...

Answer (score 4):

You need to reuse the returned String otherwise you always rewrite the whole `sentence1`. Remember the String is immutable.

```
String sentence1 = s1.toLowerCase().replace("a", "t");
sentence1 = sentence1.toLowerCase().replace("r", "m");
sentence1 = sentence1.toLowerCase().replace("e", "i");
sentence1 = sentence1.toLowerCase().replace("s", "n");
sentence1 = sentence1.toLowerCase().replace("p", "u");
```

... which can be rewritten to:

```
String sentence1 = s1.toLowerCase()
                     .replace("a", "t")
                     .replace("r", "m");
                     .replace("e", "I");
                     .replace("s", "n");
                     .replace("p", "u");
```

Comment: why would you need to re-lowercase it every time?

Comment: In such a case, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [`StringUtils.replaceChars()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceChars-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) a better approach:

```
sentence1 = StringUtils.replaceChars(s1.toLowerCase(), "aresp", "tminu");
```

Add Apache’s [commons-lang3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.11) library as a dependency.

Comment: worth mentioning that this would need an additional dependency. probably not worth it just for this use case.

Comment: apache.commons.lang3 - it's worth it. This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`String`s are immutable. You can't modify them in place, you always have to create a new object.

Example:

```
String s1 = "";
String s2 = s1 + "foo";
String s3 = s2.replace("foo", "bar");
```

`s1` and `s2` won't change, because they never get reassigned. Though the values of these variables stays the same:

```
System.out.println(s1); // ""
System.out.println(s2); // "foo"
System.out.println(s3); // "bar"
```

If you want `s1` to change, you need to reassign the new value to it:

```
String s1 = "";
s1 = s1 + "foo";
s1 = s1.replace("foo", "bar");
```

Now s1 will be `"bar"`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a text replacer that replaces every character by reducing the string according to each entry in the `Map`. You can optimize the string replacement by manipulating a `StringBuilder` object instead of a plain `String`.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TextReplacer {
    private static final Map<String, String> replacements;
    private static final List<String> phrases;

    static {
        phrases = List.of("Hello World", "Do you like peppers?");
        replacements = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("r", "m");
            put("e", "i");
            put("s", "n");
            put("p", "u");
        }};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        replaceAll(phrases, replacements).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        replaceAllOptimized(phrases, replacements).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static String replace(String phrase, Map<String, String> replacements) {
        return replacements.entrySet().stream().reduce(phrase.toLowerCase(), (s, e) -> s.replace(e.getKey(), e.getValue()), (s1, s2) -> null);
    }

    public static List<String> replaceAll(List<String> phrases, Map<String, String> replacements) {
        return phrases.stream().map(s -> replace(s, replacements)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static String replaceOptimized(String phrase, Map<String, String> replacements) {
        return replacements.entrySet().stream().reduce(new StringBuilder(phrase.toLowerCase()), (s, e) -> replaceAll(s, e.getKey(), e.getValue()), (s1, s2) -> null).toString();
    }

    public static List<String> replaceAllOptimized(List<String> phrases, Map<String, String> replacements) {
        return phrases.stream().map(s -> replaceOptimized(s, replacements)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static StringBuilder replaceAll(StringBuilder builder, String from, String to) {
        int index = builder.indexOf(from);
        while (index != -1) {
            builder.replace(index, index + from.length(), to);
            index += to.length();
            index = builder.indexOf(from, index);
        }
        return builder;
    }
}
```

### Output

```
hillo womld
do you liki uiuuimn?
hillo womld
do you liki uiuuimn?
```